# What's wrong with gcc version before 4.4 implementation on thread local storage?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, thread-local-storage

I saw this,

> ## warning "GCC versions before 4.4 implement thread_local storage incorrectly, so you can not use some parts of Loki."

in the loki library source code. More details on this page:

http://sourceforge.net/p/loki-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/include/loki/ThreadLocal.h#l53

So, What's wrong with gcc version before 4.4 implementation on thread local storage?

Comment: I don't know whether this page is accurate, but according to [Status of Experimental C++0x Support in GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) `Thread-local storage N2659` is simply *No*. It's listed as *Yes* in [4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html)

Comment: Because of bugs! There are lots of bug reports in gcc-4.4 [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=thread) about threads.

Comment: Why do you care? GCC 4.4 is an ancient version (from 2009) of the compiler. Current GCC is 4.9, and 5.0 should be released in a few weeks (spring 2015).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I do care, because recently, I encounter a wired problem, details on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512627/wired-core-dump-because-of-gcc-thread-keyword?noredirect=1#comment45345797_28512627

Comment: Then upgrade your compiler....

Comment: Yes, try upgrading to clang.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, do you know the details of the bug?